# How to translate standalone noun + a ます verb (in a heading)

Tags: meaning

I would like to know how to translate something like this:

> ドロボー、つかまえます

where there is a noun followed by a verb in masu from without any other details.

Is it something like "Burglar, I('ll) catch him" or "The catch of the burglar"?

Comment: without context I would say it is the former.

Comment: It's just a case of particle elision. Put back the を and it should be fine.

Comment: Is that "the" burglar? If it were ドロボー、つかまえて or ドロボー、つかまえるぞ, it would be "the" burger. However, ドロボー、つかまえます sounds like "We catch burglars/thieves" to me.

Answer (score 3):

I recognize this pattern from the titles of 黒{くろ}執{しつ}事{じ} (Black Butler) [episodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Black_Butler_episodes#Episode_list). The pattern is that case is `[noun], [adjective]`, and it's directly translated into English that way.

> その執{しつ}事{じ}、有{ゆう}能{のう}
>
> His Butler, Able

From that I'd say that you would say something like: "The/that burglar, I'll catch him"

That being said, this format is a little poetic in English, so I would only use it in something like a title, where you can use some creative licenses...If this where a person speaking I would say something more like "I *will* catch that burglar!"

Comment: If this isn't right, can someone correct me, instead of just donwvoting. Much more helpful that way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the permissibility of [NはADです]->[N、AD] as given doesn't necessarily imply the permissibility of [NをVます]->[N, Vます]. If you were getting downvoted, it might be bcuz ppl don't like your description of "The/that burglar, I'll catch him" being poetic. You should rather say stylized or deviant. Old English did not have the modern SVO word order of today, both SOV and VSO were both acceptable in Old English. Instead case particles had the role of word order. That's why mixing word order can sometimes seem novel or exotic (read poetic) when in fact it's just old syntax (read literary).

Comment: @taylor: Thanks for your input :) I feel like the reason some people found this answer lacking was because it's a little more anecdotal than definitive. I can't say for sure the linguistics behind this construction, but I thought I'd give my understanding of it.